# How to use an existing SSL certificate for a LAN server?

Tags: ssl, https, server, certificate, lan

I am creating a new LAN server with https enabled in my organization, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to work out SSL Certs. Manually creating a cert and adding it to a specific computer's browser allows that computer to access the local https site, but installing it manually on each computer in the network is not realistic. Is there any way to use a group policy to add a new one to all the computers, or use an existing SSL cert to validate my website? There is one existing one for the organization already, which I noticed is on all the computers on the network already, but I'm not sure how to use it.
This may be a stupid question, but basically I just need a local server to use https. Any help would be great.

Comment: See my (just-updated!) [long list of previous Qs on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69499225/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-sites-intended-to-b/69502627#69502627) some though not all of which are for Windows domains.

Comment: Thank you, these look like a great resource! I appreciate it.